# Write in a specific line in a multiline textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I want to create a calculator and I want to show the result in a line in a text box and the complete calculation in another line in the same textbox:
Example: I press 2+3+4

2+3+4 //Line1

9     //Line2

Now I press + 5

2+3+4+5//Line 1

14    //Line 2

I know how to append text to a textbox

```
textBox1.text+="5"
```

How can I append text to a specific line?

Comment: Are you really using VBA, or VB.NET ?  Not the same thing at all.

Comment: (a) Appending text in VB.Net should be `textBox1.text &= "5"`.  In VBA it should be `textBox1.text = textBox1.text & "5"` (b) Why does it need to be the same textbox - why not just position two textboxes above each other on the form?  (c) How is your code handling the "I press + 5" - are you using the `Change` event or a button?  (i.e. if using the `Change` event, are you ignoring the change if they have just pressed the `+` and then processing it when the `5` is also pressed?  What happens if they were pressing `+51`?)

Answer (score 0):

use a listBox instead

this code shows you how it could behave

create a form and place a listbox on it

paste this code

click on form background to run the code.  look at listbox and press F5 to continue code

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()

    ListBox1.Clear
    ListBox1.AddItem "0"
    ListBox1.AddItem "0"

    Stop

    ListBox1.RemoveItem "0"
    ListBox1.AddItem "2+3+4", "0"
    ListBox1.RemoveItem "1"
    ListBox1.AddItem "9", "1"

    Stop

    ListBox1.RemoveItem "0"
    ListBox1.AddItem "2+3+4+5", "0"
    ListBox1.RemoveItem "1"
    ListBox1.AddItem "14", "1"

    Stop

End Sub
```

Comment: But how would the user enter the "+5" after entering the "2+3+4" to start with?

Comment: (But, come to think of it, how is the OP intending the user to enter text into the middle portion of a single textbox?!?!?  So perhaps the idea of a [multi-line] listbox echoing what is happening in a [single-line] textbox isn't as strange as it first sounded.)

Comment: i think that the OP wants to have a display of the calculation progress only. i am making an assumption that there are buttons involved.   .... something like an RPN calculator with the stack display